# How to manipulate and randomise a variable in a while loop condition?

Tags: java, random, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a while loop with a condition inside called card1Hp and it is a new instance variable defined at the top of the class called Game.

```
    public int card1Hp = 100;
    public int card2Hp = 80;
    public int card3Hp = 90;
    public int card4Hp = 70;
```

and there's a method in the class with a while loop:

```
 while(card1Hp > 0)
```

I have a method in the class that generates a specified random number for me  where I can go:

```
someVar= Game.getRandIntBetween(1,5);
```

and it generates randVar = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5.
Is there any way I can put this into my while loop condition.
Basically I want it to be:

```
while(card1Hp > 0)
```

replaced with some kind of way like this

```
 while(card(randVar)Hp > 0)
```

I know that isn't the way to write it in java but that's the effect I want to try and generate the random number I want in my cardHp. What's a good way to achieve this? I plan for hundreds of cardhp variables in my game as well to randomize.

Comment: Do you want to use a random variable every time the condition is checked, or just one randomly selected variable for the whole while loop's condition?

Comment: You should be able to put the random code into its own function that returns an integer. From there you may be able to setup your while loop with the return of that function > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put your hp values into an array:

```
int[] hps = {card1Hp, card2Hp, card3Hp, card4Hp};
```

If you want to use a different hp value each time the while loop condition is checked, you can do this:

```
while (hps[Game.getRandIntBetween(0, hps.length - 1)] > 0)
```

Otherwise, do this:

```
int randIndex = Game.getRandIntBetween(0, hps.length - 1);
while (hps[randIndex] > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array. Something like `static int[] hpValues = { 100, 80, 90, 70 };`, then get a random number `x` between `0` (inclusive) and `hpValues.length` (exclusive) and your random "cardhp" is `int randCardHP = hpValues[x];` - and that might look like

```
int x = Game.getRandIntBetween(1, hpValues.length) - 1;
```